# Predictive input doesn’t work on Russian language

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, language

I have iPhone 7 with iOS 11.4 and my keyboard freezes at random times for second. Now it doesn’t show predictive suggestions for the Russian language.

I tried to disable all smart features of keyboard and re-enable them, remove Russian keyboard and add it back, reset keyboard dictionary, reset all content and settings, update to iOS 12 and downgrade via iTunes, restore from iTunes. Now I’m going to restore from DFU, but I’m in desperation.

This is what the problem looks like. In English the predictive bar is normal. But in Russian keyboard there are no words, just three empty spaces.

[image: problem]
[image: all okay]

Comment: Please don't put 'problem solved' in the title & the answer in the question. If you found an answer yourself, put it in the answer space then mark it as accepted. See the [Help Centre](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help) specifically [Can I answer my own question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Post your answer below as a proper answer! The question should just have the question in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DFU restore to iOS 12, than to iOS 11.4 solves problem.

How to do DFU restore: https://help.ifixit.com/article/108-dfu-restore

If you want to install custom downloaded version of iOS (that must be signed by Apple) click "Restore" in iTunes with pressed Alt/Option key (Shift on a PC). Then window with selection of .ipsw file will be appear.

Comment: Thank you for adding your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on *how* to actually carry out what's in your answer. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.

Comment: What do you really need? It really answer my question, what else can be added?

Comment: Ah, well, for example a user may not know how to do a DFU restore, so instructions on how to do that would be useful.